# NHibernate ISessionFactory.OpenSession() does not open a database connection

Tags: nhibernate, postgresql, npgsql

I have NHibernate configured with Fluent NNibernate connecting to a PostgreSQL database.

I have a worker class that takes an ISessionFactory as a constructor parameter and consumes messages from a queue. For each message the worker process calls ISessionFactory.OpenSession() and it does some database processing.

When I add more worker processes the performance of the system remains the same which is odd.
After some more investigation I realized that all worker processes are using a single database connection. For example I would add 8 worker processes but on the database I can see only one database connection.

My understanding is that ISessionFactory.OpenSession() will open a new database connection unless the Connection Pool is full.

So is my understanding wrong or is this and issue with the Postgres NHibernate driver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenSession does not open a database connection until needed, and it closes it (i.e. releases it back into the pool) as soon as possible.

Comment: My problem probably lies in how messages are consumed and not with how NHibernate handles connections.

Answer (score 3):

By default the session will keep the connection open for the life time of a transaction and as Diego said, it only opens it when needed.

If you want to manage your own connections you can call

```
ISessionFactory.OpenSession(myConnection);
```

Comment: That's correct. However, there are many drawbacks with user-managed connections, so they are strongly discouraged.